# Virtual Allocation - Hardware and Software dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, operating-system

What are the OS/Software settings, that have significance in Virtual memory allocation.

Because virtual memory for a particular address always success in my colleagues Win-7 Pc,but  it always fails in my Win-7 pc.

Hardware wise there is no difference .i just want to know what are all the software/OS parameter i should cross-verify with my colleagues pc.

Language using: `Visual Studio`

Os: Windows-7 64 bit Laptop

Comment: This question looks like a hardware based question, Stack Overflow is a website just for programming. Maybe you can [try another website](http://stackexchange.com/sites) from those under stack exchange network.

Comment: How can you confirm that it is virtual-memory? Also, do both of you have same amount of RAM?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** [Windows Sysinternals VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) can give you quite good insight into the virtual memory layout in a particular process. If comparing visualizations provided by this tool on the 2 PCs does not help then...

**2)** ...Google: "virtual memory configuration windows 7" should throw you quite quickly in the right direction

**3)** Also in your original question https://stackoverflow.com/q/25263223/2626313 the problem with exact address may be that the address range is already used by a hardware component. You can check that by using `Control Panel → Device Manager`, switch menu `View → Resources by type` and check what you see under the `Memory` node [image]

**4)** finally this https://superuser.com/a/61604/304578 article contains link to Mark Russinovich's (original author of the Windows Sysinternals tool set) explaining blog article perhaps related to your problem